# How to use require if it is not defined in this Node.js context?

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-modules, require, referenceerror

I run this:

```
$ node inspect cypress/support/reset-fixture.js teardown
```

In that file I have a call to a place where there is a `debugger;` statement.

I type `c` to continue to that place.

Once I get there, I type `repl` and in the repl I type `require`.

I get an error saying that in that place there is no `require`: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

The terminal session is below:

```
 /m/s/S/L/T/volto-slate-project > node inspect cypress/support/reset-fixture.js teardown                                             
< Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/0b6b3784-8e0c-4c35-8baa-46ea102b4bfa
< For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
< Debugger attached.
Break on start in cypress/support/reset-fixture.js:1
> 1 const xmlrpc = require('xmlrpc');
  2 
  3 // const args = process.argv;
debug> c
break in node_modules/xmlrpc/lib/client.js:119
 117 
 118     if (response.statusCode == 404) {
>119       debugger;
 120       callback(__enrichError(new Error('Not Found')))
 121     }
debug> repl
Press Ctrl + C to leave debug repl
> require
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/media/silviu/Samsung_T5/Lucru/Tibi/volto-slate-project/node_modules/xmlrpc/lib/client.js:119:7), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/media/silviu/Samsung_T5/Lucru/Tibi/volto-slate-project/node_modules/xmlrpc/lib/client.js:119:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:596:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:469:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
```

If I do not type `c` in the above-presented session, `require` seems to exist and can be used.

How can I use require after that `c`?

I use this Node version: v12.18.0.

Thank you.

## Update

I have posted an answer, but further explanation would help. A more detailed answer that explains how things work behind the scenes would be very nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I put this line:

```js
console.dir(require);
```

before the line:

```js
debugger;
```

then when the `debugger;` line is hit, in the `repl` of the Node debugger the `require` function is defined well.